# Clear CSS Transitions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I use a CSS framework which applies transitions on moving the mouse over input elements.
I have a class which I want to not have this transition. Is this possible?

Comment: please push your code for better understanding

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just put transition:none; in the css and make its priority higher than the others.

Example:

html:

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
```

​
css:

```
div.a {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #EEE;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
div.a:hover {
    background-color: #069;
}
div.a.b {
    -webkit-transition: none;
}​
```