# Set opacity of dynamically created div right after created

Tags: javascript, css

I have a button that triggers a javascript code which creates dynamically a modal window. I'd like to make it appear from opacity 0 to 1 in 2 seconds. So the javascript is:

```
modalWindow.style.opacity = 0;
document.body.appendChild(modalWindow); 
modalWindow.innerHTML = '<div>header</div><div>etc,etc...';
modalWindow.style.opacity = 1;
```

And in the CSS style there is:

```
modalWindow {transition: opacity 2s ease-out;}
```

which is loaded at start.

So I want it to fade in but when I push the button it just appears directly with opacity 1 and doesn't make the transition.

Comment: Does it have to be opacity?

Comment: What about if you apply an additional class with a `{transition: clear}` and remove that class when you want it to animate? Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630338/clear-css-transitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens due to the browser not noticing that the modal window starts with an opacity of 0.
If you use `setTimeout` to make the change of the opacity happen later, it works:

```
modalWindow.style.opacity = 0;
document.body.appendChild(modalWindow); 
modalWindow.innerHTML = 'headeretc,etc...';
setTimeout(function() {
    modalWindow.style.opacity = 1;
}, 0);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U25zu/